# Calling document.getElementByName.Value inside html event handler

Tags: javascript, html, onkeyup

Just wondering if this would be a valid syntax.

```
<input type="text" name="memtype" value="1" onkeyup="javascript:gettype(document.getElementsByName('memtype').value);>
```

Comment: Valid syntax, yes, but probably not what you want.

Comment: Why's that? Alexander O'mara.

Comment: `document.getElementsByName` returns a `NodeList`, not a single element, so `.value` of the list will be undefined.

Comment: I changed it to getElementById so Im guessing that's what you were referring to.

Comment: To refer to the element with the `onclick` attribute, just can just use `this` (ie: `javascript:gettype(this.value)`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not be valid because `getElementsByName` is a collection and need to pass the index like

```
document.getElementsByName('memtype')[0]
```

```js
function gettype(val) {
  console.log(val)
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="memtype" value="1" onkeyup="javascript:gettype(document.getElementsByName('memtype')[0].value);">
```

The same operation can be done by just passing the value using `this.value`

```js
function gettype(val) {
  console.log(val)
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="memtype" value="1" onkeyup="gettype(this.value)">
```

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByName` returns collection. To get the value from that collection you have to use specific index, like:

```
document.getElementsByName('memtype')[0].value
```

But why to write `document.getElementsByName('memtype').value` when you can write `this.value`.

```js
function getvalue(val){
  console.log(val)
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="memtype" value="1" onkeyup="javascript:getvalue(this.value);"/>
```